# Java date format - GMT +04:00

Tags: java, simpledateformat, datetime-parsing

I have to parse the following date

Fri Sep 30 18:31:00 GMT+04:00 2016

and it is not working with the following pattern:

`new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z YYYY", Locale.ENGLISH);`

I get the following date as output: Fri Jan 01 18:31:00 GMT+04:00 2016.

Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What output/error do you get?

Comment: I don't get any errors but I get the following date as output:
Fri Jan 01 18:31:00 GMT+04:00 2016

Comment: FYI, `SimpleDateFormat` is now legacy, supplanted by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be lower case "y":

```
EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy
```

Upper case "Y" means [weekBasedYear](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html#weekBasedYear--):

> a date can be created from a week-based-year, week-of-year and
>   day-of-week

I guess mixing the week-based and absolute/era patterns just does not work well for parsing.

Comment: Thank you) yes that was the issue

Comment: @dieter I got the similar problem. Can you help me? Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76431424/cannot-parse-date-containing-gmt-to-timestamp-in-java-unparseable-date-issue

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```java
OffsetDateTime
.parse
(
    "Fri Sep 30 18:31:00 GMT+04:00 2016" ,
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss O uuuu" , Locale.US ) 
)
.toString()
```

> 2016-09-30T18:31+04:00

## Avoid legacy classes

The other Answers are now outmoded. The terrible `Date`, `Calendar`, and `SimpleDateFormat` classes are now legacy, supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

## *java.time*

Your input string represents a date with time-of-day in the context of an offset-from-UTC. An offset is a number of hours ahead or behind of the baseline of [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). For this kind of information, use `OffsetDateTime` class.

Note that an offset-from-UTC is *not* a time zone. A time zone is a history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region.

The [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class replaces `SimpleDateFormat`. The formatting codes are similar, but not exactly the same. So carefully study the Javadoc.

Notice that we pass a `Locale`. This specifies the human language and cultural norms to use in parsing the input, such as the name of the month, name of the day-of-week, the punctuation, the capitalization, and so on.

```java
package work.basil.example.datetime;

import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Parsing
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        Parsing app = new Parsing();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        String input = "Fri Sep 30 18:31:00 GMT+04:00 2016";
        DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss O uuuu" , Locale.US );
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input , f );

        System.out.println( "odt = " + odt );
    }
}
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score -1):

Below code is working fine

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class ParseDate {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat parserSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date date = parserSDF.parse("Fri Sep 30 18:31:00 GMT+04:00 2016");
        System.out.println("date: " + date.toString());
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I got the similar problem. Can you help me? Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76431424/cannot-parse-date-containing-gmt-to-timestamp-in-java-unparseable-date-issue